# Is there a way to disable dragging (drag-n-drop) in a read-write dmg file?

Tags: terminal, finder, install, automator, dmg

I´m creating a **dmg image** that **should be able** to use **drag-n-drop of a folder onto an application**.

The user **installs my app by dragging a folder *onto* an application** (.app) that is made by ***Automator*** and installs the folder by copying it to the correct location. It does not install into the Applications folder, it´s in the User´s own directories. So not something one can use an Alias or symlink for.

The only problem is that the DMG converted to read-only (*compressed, in Disk Utility*) **does not allow one to drop anything into anything**, not even onto my little install app. (! :/)

**One solution** is to use a ***read-write DMG*** file. Not a good alternative. The user will mess up the order or positioning of the folders and files before installing and come back to a messed up installer app later on, for next time around. Also, it does not auto-open on double-clicking on the .dmg. That´s why you make them read-only.

So, can I disable dragging and essentially "lock" the file´s location in the read-write enabled DMG file format?

For solutions, any way is interesting, by terminal or any app.

Comment: Why would positions of files and folders matter/affect the way a program is installed ?  And, in some bizarro land where this is the case, should you not seek to rectify this, as it sounds like a massive flaw in any sort of implementation that perhaps ought not to be considering distribution.

Comment: This question is contradictory.  Your title asks to *disable* drag/drop then your 1st sentence says the user *should* be able to use drag/drop.   You also appear to *want* the user to have drag/drop capability but don't want them messing up the order.  This seems to be This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) at the dev level.  What exactly are you looking for and what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to disable drag-n-dropping of icons in Finder for a specific read-write DMG from within the DMG.

You should consider creating your installer in a different manner. For example consider using a read-only DMG with an app inside that the user needs to double click. When double clicked it will present a window allowing the user to drag-n-drop onto that area and doing whatever you wanted doing initially.